# Late 70's or early 80's Movie or TV Series or Chapter of a series including aliens from planets populated by one gender only in conflict

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The story it's about 2 groups of humanoid aliens living in planet earth, both groups are in conflict with each other, and each group are from a different planet, one populated only for women and the other only for men.

Comment: Probably not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Are_from_Mars,_Women_Are_from_Venus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like [Star Maidens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maidens)

From wiki:

The series presents a "battle of the sexes" and role reversal scenario in which male protagonists must escape servitude to women of an advanced civilization. The planet Medusa, home to a highly evolved and technologically advanced humanoid race, was already ruled by its women when a rogue comet knocked it out of its orbit of Proxima Centauri. - The series begins with Medusa's entry into Earth's solar system. At first heartened to discover Earth, the Medusans are disappointed to learn that the human men are dominant there.

Comment: I thought there was only me who was into Star Maidens ..my sacred viewing time back in the 1970's!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it may be the one I recall. I'm 46 years old now, and assume I was around 10 or 12 when I saw this series for the first time, because of that I didn't remember very well the argument, but today watch a review on the web and that convinced me.  Thanks again.

Comment: I seem to recall the opening titles being better than the show itself. ;) Glad I could help.